# How to remove auto created column id in sequelize v6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm trying to set up a model that connects to a VIEW in my postgres database so I can read from it but everytime I try to get data from the view I get an error that says column 'id' does not exist. Sequelize automatically creates an id integer column as the primary key when a model is created but since my views dont have an id column it throws an error. I've seen how to remove the id column using sequelize.define(). However I'm using a class based model and I dont know how to remove the attribute that way. Any ideas are greatly appreciated! Thanks!. Using sequelize version 6

I tried using removeAttr at the bottom but that didnt work.

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Prjt_source_percent_each extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  Prjt_source_percent_each.init({
    project_id: DataTypes.STRING,
    phase: DataTypes.STRING,
    commodity: DataTypes.STRING,
    comm_type: DataTypes.STRING,
    source_energy_baseline: DataTypes.REAL,
    source_energy_savings: DataTypes.REAL,
    savings_percent: DataTypes.DOUBLE
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Prjt_source_percent_each',
    tableName: 'prjt_source_percent_each',
    removeAttr: 'id'
  });
  return Prjt_source_percent_each;
};
```

Comment: update the question with the version of sequelize please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try using:

```
Prjt_source_percent_each.removeAttribute('id');
```

before returning the Model definition? More details: [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-removeAttribute](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-removeAttribute)

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Prjt_source_percent_each extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  Prjt_source_percent_each.init({
    project_id: DataTypes.STRING,
    phase: DataTypes.STRING,
    commodity: DataTypes.STRING,
    comm_type: DataTypes.STRING,
    source_energy_baseline: DataTypes.REAL,
    source_energy_savings: DataTypes.REAL,
    savings_percent: DataTypes.DOUBLE
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Prjt_source_percent_each',
    tableName: 'prjt_source_percent_each',
  });
  // remove the attribute
  // https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-removeAttribute
  Prjt_source_percent_each.removeAttribute('id');
  return Prjt_source_percent_each;
};
```